# Function to get the time complexity graph of any function/program

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, decorator

I am new in the developing community and I was wondering if there is any function or method you use to decide which algorithm has the best performance and therefore use it instead of any other.

For example:
I am using a decorator to know how long the functions are taking to solve problems, but I dont think that is extrapolable, hence, I was thinking maybe there is a general method or function you use to decide which algorithm to use.

Can you help me please?

Example I was using the time library to know how long two independent functions take to count the negative numbers in an array:

```
import time

def time_it(func):
    def wrapper(*args,**kwargs):
        start=time.time()
        result=func(*args,**kwargs)
        end=time.time()
        print(func.__name__ +" took " +str((end-start)*1000) + " mil seconds")
        return result
    
    return wrapper
```

```
array=[
    [-4, -3, -1, 1],
    [-2, -2, 1, 2],
    [-1, 1, 2, 3],
    [1, 2, 4, 5]
]

@time_it
def count_negatives(array):
    count=0
    for i in array:
        for j in i:
            if j < 0:
                count +=1
    return count

@time_it
def count_neg(array):
    count=0
    row=0
    column=0
    while row<len(array) and column<len(array[0]):
        if array[row][column]<0:
            count +=1
            column +=1
        else:
            row +=1
            column=0
    return count


print(count_negatives(array))
print(count_neg(array))
```

Comment: With enough sample timing data, you can develop an empirical "estimate" of the theoretical time complexity of the algorithm.  For polynomial time algorithms, plot the runtime vs input size on a log-log plot, and the slope of the best-fit line is the order of the polynomial. For exponential time algorithms, you can use a similar trick with `log(time)`, and for logarithmic time algorithms - `log(inputSize)`.

Comment: I don't see a question here except "Can you help me please?", which is really a request. Stack Overflow is for specific questions with definite answers - please see [ask] and [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @kaya3, the question is implied in the first paragraph, thanks for the comment about how to use the platform.

Answer (score 1):

An algorithm runs according to some input given to it and as well the operations its doing on it (and other variables).

With enough sampling, you can plot graphs (I prefer the `matplotlib` library) and see which one handles the input you're giving it the best.

Keep in mind these will be only samples from your own "computer" - meaning it may run faster or slower for others.

Here we can use the `time_it` decorator you've written with a little change:

- I would prefer using `time.perf_counter()` as it uses the fastest clock cycles thus can give more accurate results than just `time.time()`
- The decorator will return the actual time it took in milliseconds.
- I'll change some names so it will be easier to follow + remove the return value as we don't care about the answer of whether an array contains a negative number.

```py
import time

def time_it(func):
    def wrapper(*args,**kwargs):
        start=time.perf_counter()
        result=func(*args,**kwargs)
        end=time.perf_counter()
        return (end - start) * 1_000 # return is in milliseconds!
    
    return wrapper


@time_it
def count_negatives_v1(array):
    count = 0
    for i in array:
        for j in i:
            if j < 0:
                count += 1


@time_it
def count_negatives_v2(array):
    count = 0
    row = 0
    column = 0
    while row < len(array) and column < len(array[0]):
        if array[row][column] < 0:
            count += 1
            column += 1
        else:
            row += 1
            column = 0
```

We can now build some function that generates list of lists containing random integers between any range we choose! I've chosen that it could generate a list that contain 500-1000 lists, and these "inner" lists contain 50 numbers each can be between -1000 and 1000

```py
def generate_arrays(inner_lists_amount=(500, 1000), numbers=(-1_000, 1_000), inner_lists_length=50):
    inner_arrays_count = random.choice(range(*inner_lists_amount))
    return [list(random.choices(range(*numbers), k=inner_lists_length)) for _ in range(inner_arrays_count)]
```

This will generate up `inner_arrays_quantity` inner arrays to inner arrays, each one containing 50 number between -1000 and 1000.
Then we will pass it to each of the function you've written: (e.g. `v1`, `v2`) and get the result, we will save the output as our "y" values on the graph, the "x" values will be the sample index, here I've chosen sample amount of 1000 meaning it will call 1000 times the `generate_arrays`, pass it to `v1` and `v2` and save the results for each of these methods in a different "y" value lists:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def build_graphs(sample_count=100):

    x = range(sample_count)
    y_v1 = []
    y_v2 = []
    for _ in range(sample_count):
        print(_)
        arrays = generate_arrays()
        y_v1.append(count_negatives_v1(arrays))
        y_v2.append(count_negatives_v2(arrays))

    plt.plot(x, y_v1, 'r')
    plt.plot(x, y_v2, 'g')
    plt.show()
```

Using the `matplotlib` module we coloured the second method (v2) with green and v1 in red.

This will give us results as following:

[image]

Now this is not 100% accurate and will never be as it depends on a lot of things such as:

- PC memory
- CPU clock rate sampling the time
  and much more, but can be somewhat be improved if for each call of the `generate_arrays` we do X more tests and check the average time it takes on each specific array. Because here we tested only once how much time it takes for `v1, v2` to run on each array... however because the sample amount is 1000 it gives fairly the same results as expected.

Note: this does not give the actual order of the functions (big-o) - if you want to do it, then you can give it increasing amount of data, plotting it into excel and use a trendline with the highest `R` value to find the best graph function that has the nearest to 100%.

More info using the [openpyxl module](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.chart.trendline.html)